# which command will give complete user creation in RHEL?

Tags: users, group, useradd

I want to create a user in RHEL 6.5 and i have three commands 
(1)useradd
(2)adduser
(3)system-config-users
which one will give the complete user creation.

Answer (score 4):

`adduser` is there for compatibility with older versions of RHEL, and with other OSes.

For purely command-line operation, `useradd` is [the preferred method](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-users-cl-tools.html#cl-creating-user).

`system-config-users` doesn't fit in the same category as the other two. It is a GUI program. It's implemented in terms of `userhelper`, which has a command line I/O interface more suitable for use as the back-end to a GUI program.

(This according to [its man page](http://usr-share-man.org/man8/userhelper.html). Its man page also says it's not meant to be used interactively, so it doesn't replace `useradd` for your purposes.)

Bottom line, use `system-config-users` if you want a GUI, and use `useradd` if you want a command line app.

Comment: Thank you, after creation of user in either way which among these will give the complete user with all default setting without fail.

Comment: I answer that in the final paragraph. If you know a condition where either of these tools fails, you probably have the seed of a new question.

Comment: Thank you.  i am launching GUI app in custom desktop in the user login which i have created in two ways. It is launching good with system-config-users. and it is not launching with useradd.

Comment: You are probably neglecting to give the user a password in the `useradd` case. This is step 2 in the first link I gave above. I just tried it on a CentOS 6 VM, and `useradd` followed by `passwd` created a user I was able to log in as and run GUI programs.

Comment: Thank you, one more question is when i created a user with two ways one is with useradd and second one is system-config-users and when i logout from root it was able to logout with system-config-uses and with useradd it is giving balck screnn message as starting certmonger and it won't boot afterwards.

Comment: @subbarao: I haven't the slightest idea what you're talking about, but Stack Exchange isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site: you post one question, you get one or more answers. If you want someone to diagnose your system's failure to reboot, that's a separate matter worth a separate question. I don't think it has anything to do with the other user you added, though.